# I want to make a better tree than st_tree

Tags: c++, templates, data-structures, tree

At https://github.com/erikerlandson/st_tree you will find a good template for creating trees for instance you can write:

```
tree<string, ordered<> > t;
t.insert("A");

// Insert strings at ply 1
node_iterator c = t.root().insert("C");
t.root().insert("B");
t.root().insert("D");

// Insert strings at ply 2
c->insert("F");
c->insert("E");
```

You can choose between ordered (using multiset), raw (using vector) and keyed node (using map), each node holds some data which also is the key for ordered and keyed node. It is not possible to make a tree with mixed type of nodes. I want to make an alternative template where the nodes not always have data but merely is a holder for some childs and also allows some mix. A simplified example could be:

```
tree  t;
t.iterator it=t.insert(new node<raw_no_data<>>);
t.iterator it2=it->insert(new node<ordered_no_data<string>>); //indicating that its childs
//data  should be string;
t.iterator it3=it->insert(new node<keyed_no_data<string>>);
it2->insert(new node<leave,string>(“B”));
it3->insert(new node<leave_key,string,int>(“D”,5));

node_base &n1=t[0].find(“B”); //looking in multiset
node_base &n2=t[1].find(“D”); //looking in map
```

In other words in a more general case, I want the option to access a node like this:
mynode=t[2][0]["cat"][1];
Where tree is a mix of ordered and raw nodes, and where we have no _data for childs of the raw node.
Does something like this already exist as open source? If not I will try to make such a project and upload it on GitHub.

Comment: I am unclear on what you are asking. `tree<string*, ordered<> > t;` is not sufficient?

Comment: @user4581301. I wish I could edit my question. tree<string*, ordered<> > t; means an ordered tree using string as keys, stored in _data (A protected member of the node_base). In some cases you don't need the _data at all, if you just know the index. For instance     // Default child node storage model is raw<>, which provides a vector<> - like interface.
    tree<const char*> t;
It is of couse nice to know that a raw tree in this case stores char* as _data but what if you don't need it. I am actually only interested in the data for the leaves.

Comment: @user4581301 I can edit know. My issue here is to minimize the memory usage.

Comment: It looks like you want a heterogeneous collection. One way to do this is to have various types of collection elements (nodes in your case) inherit from common base class. One problem here is dispatching of the subscript operator. You will need to make sure the `operator[]()` template in the base class calls the appropriate access method in the deruved class or fails.